# program stucks when running transformers example code

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have some problem when trying to run the example code from transformers github page (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) using geany, visual studio code or the terminal. I'm using python 3.6 on Windows. The code of the example is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets
from transformers import *

# Load dataset, tokenizer, model from pretrained model/vocabulary
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
model = TFBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
data = tensorflow_datasets.load('glue/mrpc')

# Prepare dataset for GLUE as a tf.data.Dataset instance
train_dataset = glue_convert_examples_to_features(data['train'], tokenizer, max_length=128, task='mrpc')
valid_dataset = glue_convert_examples_to_features(data['validation'], tokenizer, max_length=128, task='mrpc')
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(100).batch(32).repeat(2)
valid_dataset = valid_dataset.batch(64)

# Prepare training: Compile tf.keras model with optimizer, loss and learning rate schedule
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5, epsilon=1e-08, clipnorm=1.0)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=[metric])

# Train and evaluate using tf.keras.Model.fit()
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=115,
                    validation_data=valid_dataset, validation_steps=7)

# Load the TensorFlow model in PyTorch for inspection
model.save_pretrained('./save/')
pytorch_model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('./save/', from_tf=True)

# Quickly test a few predictions - MRPC is a paraphrasing task, let's see if our model learned the task
sentence_0 = "This research was consistent with his findings."
sentence_1 = "His findings were compatible with this research."
sentence_2 = "His findings were not compatible with this research."
inputs_1 = tokenizer(sentence_0, sentence_1, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors='pt')
inputs_2 = tokenizer(sentence_0, sentence_2, add_special_tokens=True, return_tensors='pt')

pred_1 = pytorch_model(inputs_1['input_ids'], token_type_ids=inputs_1['token_type_ids'])[0].argmax().item()
pred_2 = pytorch_model(inputs_2['input_ids'], token_type_ids=inputs_2['token_type_ids'])[0].argmax().item()

print("sentence_1 is", "a paraphrase" if pred_1 else "not a paraphrase", "of sentence_0")
print("sentence_2 is", "a paraphrase" if pred_2 else "not a paraphrase", "of sentence_0")

input('Press any key to quit')
```

When I run that example, the program get stuck for a long time (several minutes to more than an hour) before producing a very long error message for several times:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py', line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py', line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py', line 976, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py', line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py', line 377, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py', line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py', line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py', line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File 'C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\ssl.py', line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] <<Some Chinese charaters>>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

The chinese charaters says 'the server didn't response in time, connection failed'. So it's probably a problem with internet. So how can I connect to the server, or download the files required by this program by other means?

Comment: Er.... That was all the output. It seems that the program just stuck there forever.... Maybe it is trying to download something but unable to do so?

Comment: Err...I runned that example for several more times. Sometimes it says it fail to connect to server after getting stuck for a long time.... So I think it's an internet issue